# group of elements whose orders are a power of some integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am stuck with the following problem, from C. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra", p. 153 ex. C 6:

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and $H_p$ the subset of $G$ such that the order of every $x \in H_p$ is a power of $p$. Prove that $H_p$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that $G/H_p$ has no elements whose order is a non-zero power of $p$.

So, to prove that $H_p$ is a subgroup of $G$, I need to show (among others) that it is closed under the group operation. Let $a$, $b \in H_p$, by hypothesis $\mathrm{ord}(a) = p^m, \mathrm{ord}(b) = p^n$ for some integers $m, n$. Now  consider $(ab)^{p^{mn}}$: since $G$ is abelian, this is equal to $a^{p^{mn}}b^{p^{mn}}$, which is in turn equal to $a^{{(p^m)}^n}b^{{(p^n)}^m}$, which is equal to the identity $e$, since $p^m = \mathrm{ord}(a)$ and $p^n = \mathrm{ord}(b)$.

In other words, $(ab)^{p^{mn}} = e$, hence $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$ divides $p^{mn}$.

Now here is where I am puzzled: nothing is assumed about $p$. For if $p$ were assumed to be prime (as the choice of the letter "p" seems to indicate), it would indeed seem to follow that $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$ must itself be a power of $p$.

Conversely, there seem to be counterexamples when $p$ is not prime, e.g. if we take $G = (\mathbb{Z}_{12},+)$ and set $p = 4$, then $H_4$ contains $3$ ($\mathrm{ord}(3) = 4$), but $3 + 3 = 6$ has order $2$, which is not a power of $4$. In other words, $H_4$ does not appear to be closed under the group operation ($+$, in this case).

Any comments? Thanks very much.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  $p$ needs to be prime for this to hold, and the author should have stated that $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Thanks! I'm always reluctant to assume that the book is wrong, so it seemed better to ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you are entirely correct. $p$ must be a prime for the conjecture to hold and for any proof to succeed.

That the author did not explicitly state that $p$ must be prime was a huge oversight on his part!

Comment: Thanks! I can now tackle the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas well done. In general, if $a, b \in G$ and $a$ and $b$ commute and both have finite order, then $ord(ab)$ divides lcm$(ord(a),ord(b))$.

Comment: Thanks! This rings a bell, I must have seen this earlier in the book I'm studying with. With this it becomes clear that $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$ must be a power of $p$.